# C# Redis Cache: How to check if a particualar key-value is changed and then invalidate and set the nw value from Data Tier (i.e. Original Source)

Tags: c#, redis, cache-invalidation

Looking for implementation which:

1) checks for the key if the value is changed.

2) if yes invaludates the key.

3) sets the key with new value from the Data Tier(i.e. Original Source)

Comment: Why just not call `AddOrUpdate` ?

Comment: Want to use somehting like **CacheEntryChangeMonitor Class** :
Provides a base class that represents a ChangeMonitor type that can be implemented in order to monitor changes to cache entries.

Comment: Do you want to update the cache or use CacheEntryChangeMonitor. I guess that these things are pretty different.

Comment: My ask is: My cache is implemeted and its working i want to see if any value which is there in the cache has changed in the original source. On the basis of that i want to trigger something.

AddorUpdate that you suggested can be implemented but how to knwo if value has changed in the original source.(which i guess cacheEntryMonitor Class does)

Comment: I'm not sure does it work with Redis at all.

Comment: What can be the method to see if any value for key has changed in the source?

Comment: https://techblog.betclicgroup.com/2013/12/31/implementing-local-memorycache-invalidation-with-redis/

Comment: so what's the source? another redis instance? a sql DB? please clarify your question.

Comment: source can be a SQL DB or a result coming from Service Call.